# How do I affix top my navbar with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a nav-bar that starts off at about 50px from the top of the page on load.  As I scroll down, I would like the nav-bar to "affix" itself to the very top of the page and be visible as I scroll through the rest of the content.  This is similar to what the nav-bar does on the official bootstrap tutorial Github site.
I am able to get the nav-bar to stay in place (albeit always 50px from the top as I scroll down the page) by using

```
<ul class = "nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix">
```

but once I add "-top" to the above so that it looks like

```
<ul class = "nav nav-list bs-docs-sidenav affix-top">
```

the nav-bar no longer stays in place and disappears from view as I scroll down the page.

[jsfiddle without "-top"](http://jsfiddle.net/t7Njg/)

[jsfiddle with "-top"](http://jsfiddle.net/sF4eE/)

How do I get the nav-bar to affix to the top of the page as I scroll down?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are few things to correct. See fixed [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sF4eE/2/).

1. Affix is implemented in the Bootstrap as JavaScript code using jQuery and you did not include neither BS's JS nor jQuery
2. To turn on affix for the element, according to [official documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#affix), use `data-spy="affix"`, not the `class="affix"`. Why did you do that? Classes `affix` and `affix-top` serve a different purpose - they tell you the state of the affix at the time. If at the moment your element is fixed the class is `affix`, if it is scrollable BS changes the class to `affix-top`.
3. You have to tell BS when you want the element to be fixed. The distance in pixels (how much you have to scroll) is set with the attribute `data-offset-top`. Also specify in CSS how the nav should look like when fixed. If it is binded to the top (with no space between the window border and the element) then `.affix { top:0; }` will do it.

Comment: Hi marcin, do you need both the bootstrap.js file and jQuery library cited or just one of them to implement affix?

Comment: Both. The `bootstrap.js` (or its part covering only the Affix feature - `bootstrap-affix.js`) is the Twitter's code, but it requires jQuery, as half of the Internet nowadays ;) Thanks to jQuery you can create JS more quickly and clean, but first of all it will be more portable across many different web browsers, so be thanksfull to the BS authors for using it :)